# Crypto++ DES implementation and the key length

Tags: c++, cryptography, des, crypto++

I've been looking for a crypto library for C++ for a while, and finally came across [Crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/). The library seemed OK until I tried to use [3DES](http://cryptopp.com/wiki/Tripledes). The problem is that the key length for DES algorithm implemented in this library is 64 bits (instead of usual 56 bits). I spent some time searching for explanation and all I finally got was a couple of words from the Crypto++ documentation:

> The DES implementation in Crypto++ ignores the parity bits (the least significant bits of each byte) in the key.

Does this mean that if I have a usual 56-bit key and want to decrypt some data with this library I have to "expand" my key by inserting a meaningless extra bit after every 7 bits of my key data? Or is there another way to use 56-bit keys with this wonderful library?

Comment: Note that using 3DES with a 64 bit key where all partial keys are the same, is really meaningless. It's three times slower at the same security level as DES.

Comment: [TripleDES](http://cryptopp.com/wiki/Tripledes) is usually one of two flavors: 2-key TripleDES and 3-key TripleDES. 2-key is 112-bits, and 3-key is 168-bits. Even the IETF uses it that way in the RFCs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A usual DES key is 8-bytes, it is just that the lsb (least significant bit), the parity bit, is ignored in almost all current implementations DES.

But that begs the question wether DES and/or 3DES (with 112-bit and/or 168-bit keys) should be used. The answer for DES: no, for 3DES: only for legacy compatibility. Both of these have been superseded by AES.

Comment: Thank you! And does this mean that it is common practice to generate 64-bit keys instead of 56? Or are there any other libraries that use exactly 56-bit keys?
As to the algorithm's reliability - I'm aware that it's absolutely outdated, just  need to use it for education purposes.

Comment: It is commonplace supply keys in bytes, generally either with a CPRNG (Cryptographic Pseudo random Number Generator) or a keY derivation function from a password such as (PBKDF2). The key strengths are specified in bits But supplied in bytes.

Comment: If it is just educational why not just use AES. [XTEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XTEA) is simple and reasonably secure. For educational purposed see:
[*Handbook of Applied Cryptography*](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/index.html) by Alfred J. Menezes, Paul C. van Oorschot and Scott A. Vanstone, free download and the classic [*Applied Cryptography*](https://www.schneier.com/books/applied_cryptography/) by Bruce Schneier. [*Cryptography Decrypted*](http://www.informit.com/store/cryptography-decrypted-9780201616477) by H. X. Mel and Doris M. Baker (good starter I really like).

Comment: @Zaph - *"If it is just educational why not just use AES..."* - if its historical, then there's no way to make AES the first widely known block cipher. DES also uses a different design known as a [Feistel Network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feistel_cipher).

Comment: @jww Yes, XTEA is also a Feistel cipher. For historical study I would choose RC4. DES does die hard, the finial sector is still resisting moving away from DES (3DES).